# Executing installers programmatically

Tags: java, tomcat, command-line, installation, programmatically-created

I am working on a project for my users to generate HTML pages, JS files, CSS files etc... through dragging and dropping visual elements and by going through a series of wizzards. The goal I am trying to achieve is to create an application in which users selects a runtime, for example tomcat or nodeJS and then be able to create content for that specific runtime in the manner described above. Part of this application would be the preparing of your runtime, and by that I mean installing tomcat or nodeJS for you. so the big question here would be, *how do I run installers through program code ?* (java 7/8 mainly)

**what I have tried:**

Using a strategy design pattern to determine the host platform and run a series of command in the terminal to execute an installer, problem here is that some installers start a wizzard and require further user input. and in some cases the host platform would require elevated permission. Is there perhaps a solution where one adds arguments to the terminal commands to skip an installation wizzard ?

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a reason for that you need elevated rights ... If there is a "silent" Installation mode depends on the specific installer. Is it only tomcat and nodeJS, you want to install? Have you consulted their installer-docu? Tomcat - AFAIK - has the `/S` Switch for silent Installation.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I am asking for methods to install in compliance with the host system. Currently yes, but in the (near future) every kind of software with a installer should be compatible. not really digging the idea of a different strategy extension for each piece of software.

Comment: I can see your point, but different vendors use different packagers ... I really doubt you'll have a "one fits all" here.

Comment: Well, tomcat in silent mode sure is a nice start, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of Fildor was most usefull.